# Is it possible to install DirectX by Group Policy?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy

I use a Windows Server 2003 network with windows XP clients. In the past I have rolled out new software to the client machines using group policy.

AutoDesk TrueView 2007 rolls out fine to my clients however it has been updated and the 2010 version requires DirectX to install. Can DirectX also be installed via group policy and if so where can I find the msi file required to install it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no offiically supported MSI installer for the DirectX runtimes.  If you want one, you'll either have to find a third party that has already made one, or make it yourself.  There are numerous ways you could go about trying to make one yourself.  [AppDeploy.com](http://www.appdeploy.com) is a good resource for this sort of thing.